# How do I put a JTextArea along side another JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jtextarea

I'm trying to put one `JTextArea` next to another `JTextArea` in a GUI

I am writing a GUI for a database and wanted to put the data from each column in a different JTextArea. This will make my GUI look a lot better and make it easier to view the data. I have already tried adding the `JTextAreas` to a `JPanel`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public class GUIDisplayBooks extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textAreaIsbn = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea textAreaTitle = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea textAreaSurname = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea textAreaForename = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea textAreaCategory = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);

    GUIDisplayBooks(ArrayList<Book> books)
    {
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(600,200);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    for(Book book : books){            
        textAreaIsbn.append(book.getIsbn() + "\n");
        textAreaTitle.append(book.getTitle() + "\n");
        textAreaSurname.append(book.getSurname() + "\n");
        textAreaForename.append(book.getForename() + "\n");
        textAreaCategory.append(book.getCategory() + "\n");
    }
        panel.add(textAreaIsbn);
        panel.add(textAreaTitle);
        panel.add(textAreaSurname);
        panel.add(textAreaForename);
        panel.add(textAreaCategory);
        add(scrollPane);

    }

}
```

I keep getting a blank GUI window. Maybe it's something really obvious, any help appriciated

Comment: What layout are you using? Where do you make you frame visible?

Comment: 1) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 2) *"I am writing a GUI for a database and wanted to put the data from each column in a different JTextArea."* This is the type of task that a `JTable` is **extremely** good at. Don't try to reinvent the wheel. Learn how to use a table.

Comment: Don't use multiple text areas!. See [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing components can only have a single parent:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

I basically the same of this:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
```

Then you're adding that same `panel` to your `JFrame`:

```
this.add(panel);
```

Which removes it from the `JScrollPane` and then you add the empty `JScrollPane` to the `JFrame`:

```
add(scrollPane);
```

So, removing this line, should make your program to work:

```
this.add(panel);
```

Comment: ok, thank you very much! I did as suggested and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @117Halo if the answer solved your question be sure to accept it

Comment: And I would also recommend you to take into consideration the comments of Andrew and camickr about using a `JTable`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a layout. Various implementations exists, you can take a first look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

A [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) with Horizontal orientation should do it.

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel();` means the code is **already** using a `FlowLayout`.